# How to set attribute of an instance of a model that is the sibling of a parent object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Newish to Backbone, and having some trouble. Going to try to ask this in a generic, no-code way since the application I'm tasked with maintaining is several thousand lines long... hope I can be clear.

I have a method myMethod(), that belongs to a model App.Person.

I have a collection App.PersonList that holds several instances of App.Person.

I have an instance (myPersonList) App.PersonList that I'm creating within an object (myDonationForm) that is an instance of an object App.DonationForm (and here we roam even further outside my comfort zone: App.DonationForm extends an object named Controller which extends an object called Base which seems to be a base.js thing and I have very little idea what's happening here but I hope it doesn't matter for my immediate need).

Also in App.DonationForm, I have an instance (myErrorMsg) of a model App.Errors. I would like to be able to set an attribute of myErrors from myMethod() but can't work out the syntax to refer to myErrors, traversing up the tree of nested objects and then back down a parallel step.

I hope that made sense. To visualize it:

```
myDonationForm, inst of App.DonationForm, ext Controller
|--myPersonList, inst of App.PersonList, ext Collection
|  |--myPerson[1], inst of App.Person, ext Model // I want to change from here
|  |  +---myMethod()
|  |--myPerson[2], inst of App.Person, ext Model // or from here
|     +---myMethod()
+myErrorMsg, inst of App.Errors, ext Model       // an attribute of this.
```

Thank you in advance for any pointers you can offer.

---

Edited to add a code snippet (and I accidentally tried to edit Hoyen's answer, not my own question! didn't realize it til I got the peer review screen, ugh)

```
App.SpecialDonationForm = App.DonationForm.extend({
    [...]
    initialize: function(options){
        App.DonationForm.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
        [...]
    },
    start: function(){
        App.DonationForm.prototype.start.call(this);
        [...]
        this.myPersonList = new App.PersonList(this.initialData);
        this.myErrorMsg = new App.Errors();
        [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically since myErrorMsg is an instance of a Backbone model you need to use Backbone's model methods to set the attributes. So, it should look something like this:

```
App.Person = Backbone.Model.extend(
{
    [...]
    defaults: {
        [...],
        errorMsg: new App.Errors()
    },
    [...]
    myMethod: function(){
        var value = ""; // set it to what ever you like
        this.get("errorMsg").set("message",value); // "message", is the attribute you want to update with the value 
        this.trigger('change:errorMsg'); // not sure if this is needed. but this will insure that this will trigger any event listeners on errorMsg
    }

});

App.SpecialDonationForm = App.DonationForm.extend({
    [...]
    initialize: function(options){
        App.DonationForm.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
        [...]
    },
    start: function(){
        App.DonationForm.prototype.start.call(this);
        [...]
        this.myPersonList = new App.PersonList(this.initialData);
        this.myErrorMsg = new App.Errors();
        this.myPersonList.on('change:errorMsg',showError.bind(this));
        function showError(model,val,options){
            this.myErrorMsg.set(_.extend(this.myErrorMsg.defaults,model.toJSON());
        }
        [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: myErrorMsg is not defined"

Comment: You don't have an instance of myErrorMsg in your App.Person class

Comment: I'll update my question with a pared-down code snippet.

Comment: @Sapphireblue you probably need to add a new errorMsg default value to the Person model class. In the SpecialDonationForm, you want to listen to any changes in the errorMsg from the models and do your code there

Comment: I really appreciate your time but don't think I want to go that route. I want to have an object that stores aggregate info on errors, so that even if I have ten Persons in the collection, my myErrorMsg object is just tracking whether an error has happened in any of them. all App.Errors is, is several booleans defaulted to false; I want to be able to set any of them to true from any Person--not to have to store error/status info in every Person in the collection, then later have to look at every Person to see whether there's an error in any of them. Sigh. I thought this'd be easy. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

An event aggregator may work in this scenario.

Setup to extend Backbone events

```
App.eventAgg = _.extend({object}, Backbone.Events);
```

During App.Errors initialize, listenTo an event

```
this.listenTo(App.eventAgg, 'someEvent', this.doSomeUpdate);
```

In App.Person's myMethod, trigger the event

```
App.eventAgg.trigger('someEvent');
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your generic question even more generically,

- Based on your hierarchy, a `Person` object doesn't know anything at all about the `Errors` object. Child objects don't (and shouldn't) know anything about their parents.
- A `Person` object does (presumably) know, however, that an "error" has occurred and someone might want to know about it.
- Since the `Person` object doesn't know any more than that, all it can do is trigger a custom event.
- Some other object needs to listen for this custom event. Based on your hierarchy, the only other object that has access to the `Person` object is the `PersonList` collection.
- The `PersonList` collection is now in the same situation. It has learned (from the custom event) that an error has occurred, but it can't do anything about it and it doesn't know about its parents. So all it can do is trigger another custom event.
- The `DonationForm` object has to listen for the custom events from the `PersonList` collection. When it receives the event, it can then pass it to the `Errors` object.

Voila.